# Does LeanFT supports multithreading for mainframe

Tags: multithreading, automation, leanft

Using LeanFT I’m automating mainframe via Pcomm emulator. Now I’m trying to have multithreaded (by opening multiple pcomm sessions) &    tried different approaches but LeanFT is passing data to only first session. Does LeanFT supports multithreaded, if not mainframe does anyone tried web. Please provide feed back.

Note : I’m differentiating each pcomm screen by short name of mainframe TeWindow

Answer (score 1):

LeanFT and UFT do not support multithreading for mainframe, you can work with only one session at a time.

Please check this documentation where we state this limitation:

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.1/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/TE_limitations.htm

Section: Multiple open emulator sessions